# Whats the purpose of perfect forwarding function parameters

Tags: c++

I keep seeing patterns as:

```cpp
template<class Task, class ...Args>
void add(Task&& task, Args&& ... args) {
        queue.emplace_back(std::bind(std::forward<Task>(task),std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

From what I understand, functions are pretty much every time passed via a function pointer, so is there any value in forwarding it if there is only one option (maybe if passed by reference, but not sure why we would do this)?

Similarly, why do people perfect forward to `bind()`? Am I missing something, or it is just a commonly occurring bug? I thought that `bind()` will always accept by value and hence copy whatever you pass it?

Comment: Do you know what r-values are?  Perfect forwarding preserves r-values.  With r-values, constructing does not always mean "copying" -- it can mean "moving".

Comment: What if `Task` is a callable object and not a function ?